# Error when resampling a datetime64 time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas v1.0.3 dataframe where the index is a timestamp and the one column is a numeric value. The index is at a constant time interval difference of 30 minutes. The single column represents a count, and I want to resample it so the index is a 2 day interval.

It seems that I would need to do something like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('2D', on='column_name').sum()
```

However, I am getting the following error: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'`

If I print out `df.index` I get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-31 23:59:59', '2017-01-01 00:29:59',
...
dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=500, freq='30T')
```

Which seems to be compatible. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index should be compatible, but you ask pandas to resample on a **column**. You should just do:

```
df.resample('2D').sum()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.